# How can i get the list of filenames which did not failed using valums file uploader

Tags: php, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am creating a multi file upload using valums file uploader, How can i get the list of file names that did not failed. All i have tried uptil now is this.

```
function createUploader(){            
    var UploadedFileNames = [];
            var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
            element: document.getElementById('file-uploader-demo1'),
            action: '../server/php.php',
            allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'],

            /*onSubmit: function(id, fileName){
                UploadedFileNames.push(fileName);
                        alert(UploadedFileNames);
            },*/

            onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){
                UploadedFileNames.push(fileName);
            //alert(UploadedFileNames);
            },
            debug: true
        });           
    }
```

by using this i am getting all the filenames that are uploaded but not which were successfully uploaded. Just a newbie trying to learn.
Help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is 'did not failed'? Do you want a list of those that succeeded in uploading or a list of those that failed?

Comment: @DanielHanly yes the list of those succeeded. But I got the solution.  Will post the answer as soon as i get the permission to post it. (Its stackoverflow rule answer cant be posted til 8hrs after submitting, if you have reputation less than 10.) Thanks for trying.

Comment: Just upvoted you so you have 10 reputation. Go ahead and post the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Hope this will be useful for other.

```
var UploadedFilesNames = [];        
onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){

var success = responseJSON["success"];
if(success == true){
    UploadedFileNames.push(fileName);
}

}
```